# Expression Engine SafeCracker Format Datepicker

Tags: php, javascript, datepicker, expressionengine, safecracker

Hi I am making a form in expression engine using safecracker and one of my fields called "date of birth" uses the date field type. The jQuery datapicker is being automatically added by expression engine but I can't see how to add any of the options or formatting I would normally add to datepicker when making a field of this type.

**My normal code:**

```
 $(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
        maxDate: new Date()
    });
 });
```

The only option I can think of is to make this field a text input and add the datepicker myself in the template but this would remove EE's date validation that it performs on this field type.

Is there anyway to add additional datepicker options to this field type?

Comment: what type of options you wanted to add?

Comment: The ones in my code changeMonth, changeYear, dateFormat, maxDate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you can set `datepicker="no"` in your [Safecracker tag](http://expressionengine.com/user_guide/modules/safecracker/index.html#datepicker), then add your javascript manually. However: you can't use your custom format as you show above - for the input to validate as a native EE date field, it must use the datePicker format `yy-mm-dd`, **plus** the current time in the format `HH:MM AM/PM` - which the datePicker doesn't do natively. ([See this post by one of EE's developers](http://www.derekallard.com/blog/post/adding-time-to-jquery-ui-datepicker) for how they do this.)

An alternative would be to instead use the EEvent Helper date field, because it does not require the time portion to validate (though it too requires `yy-mm-dd`). However, `datepicker="no"`only affects *native* date fields, so you'd instead have to set `safecracker_head="no"` - but then you'll also lose any javascript or CSS required by other fieldtypes in your form.

Re: using a plain text field: in addition to the validation issue, your data would then be stored as whatever is input (mm/dd/yy), instead being converted a timestamp, which is far more useful and portable.

The only true solution is to write your own date fieldtype for this. Wouldn't be very difficult.

Comment: Cheers, thanks for your help again. Your first solution sounds good because you can get datepicker to display one format and POST the required EE format of yy-mm-dd. I will also look into writing a field type though because it is always nice to have things working nicely in the backend.

Comment: Ah, I didn't know that about datePicker, very nice.

Comment: The option is called "altFormat" just for reference.

Comment: Actually you don't need the datepicker="no" option because this seems to stop any datepicker code even if you are including it separately  via the {exp:jquery:script_tag ui='datepicker'} tag. What worked for me in the end was just overwritting there datepicker by instantiating mine at the bottom of the page